Movie about a professor accused of a crime?
This movie is at least 14-15 years old.
A professor in a college is teaching his students about a recent incident when a man was accused of a crime and then killed during the shootout by the police. The professor mentioned that the life of that individual and the recent events in his life do not suggest that he had committed that crime.
Later in the movie, that professor himself got involved with some criminals and was trying to stop a terror plot. There was a long car chase scene. At the end, the car which that professor was driving blew up and he died. Then he is labeled as the criminal and the actual criminals never got apprehended.

Related question (though not really a duplicate)

It's Arlington Road from 1999 with Jeff Bridges and Tim Robbins.

Widowed when his FBI agent wife is killed in an operation against suspected terrorists, a college professor becomes increasingly obsessed with the culture and sub-society of these dangerous groups. The arrival of new neighbors, gives him new spirit, as they are gregarious and friendly, with a ten-year-old boy that his son can be friends with. He is even beginning to see another woman. However, he begins to suspect something is odd about the neighbors, something about the way they don't want him to see certain parts of the house, or a set of blueprints they have there. Are his neighbors terrorists... or is the stress of losing his wife merely driving him past the point of paranoia? 

It ends exactly as you've described. Here's the trailer:



